# CORS configuration on AWS S3 not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, html5-canvas, paperclip, fabricjs

I have rails 4 application that uses html5 canvas for t-shirt design. Fabricjs is used as Javascript HTML5 canvas library. When I add text object on canvas and call `toDataURL` method, it works fine. When I add svg image served over AWS S3 on canvas, it gets loaded on canvas but when I call `toDataURL` on canvas, it gets blank and I get following error on console:

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.
```

Initially when the images served over S3 gets loaded on document, I get the following error:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://example.com' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://example.s3.amazonaws.com/clip_arts/arts/000/000/001/thumb/1.png?1431770898'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.
```

I searched through the internet and found out it to be a CORS issue. In my AWS bucket, I added a following CORS configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>https://example.com/</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>Content-*</AllowedHeader>
        <AllowedHeader>Host</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>https://*.example.com/</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>Content-*</AllowedHeader>
        <AllowedHeader>Host</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Call to `toDataURL` works fine on firefox but doesn't works on any other browsers.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to add `crossOrigin:'Anonymous'` to the function,

```
fabric.loadSVGFromURL(svgUrl,function(objects,options) {

}, {
    crossOrigin: 'Anonymous'
});
```

And instead of having this in the CORS

```
<AllowedHeader>Content-*</AllowedHeader>
<AllowedHeader>Host</AllowedHeader>
```

Just add this to the CORS

```
<AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
```

Comment: I'm using `fabric.Image.fromURL` to add image on canvas and when I added crossOrigin:"anonymous" in that function I get error `Image from origin blocked. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`. I also used `fabric.loadSVGFromURL` and got error `Mixed Content: The page at 'https://' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint`. In both cases, image didn't get loaded in canvas.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Khawer Zeshan answer..

I had the same problem using `toDataURL` on Chrome. I added `<AllowedOrigin>Anonymous</AllowedOrigin>` in addition to `<AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>` to AWS S3 CORS config. It worked for me.