# Fabric loadSVGFromURL issue with CORS in AWS S3

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors, fabricjs

I have SVG files stored in a AWS S3 bucket which I use them to put it on my canvas using FabricJS loadSVGFromURL , but it shows CORS error

[image]

This is the code:

```
fabric.loadSVGFromURL(url,function(objects, options){

  var obj = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
  obj.scaleToHeight(canvas.height-120).set({ 
    left: (canvas.width / 2) - ((obj.width * obj.scaleX) / 2), 
    top: (canvas.height / 2) - ((obj.height * obj.scaleY) / 2),
    borderColor: '#eaeaea',
    cornerColor:'#eaeaea',
    cornerSize:10,
    cornerStyle:'circle',
    transparentCorners:false,
    lockUniScaling:true,
    fill:"#000000",
    id:"svg_0",
    url_svg: url
  }).setCoords();

  canvas.add(obj).renderAll();
});
```

This is the CORS policy of AWS bucket:

```
[
{
    "AllowedHeaders": [
        "*"
    ],
    "AllowedMethods": [
        "PUT",
        "POST",
        "DELETE"
    ],
    "AllowedOrigins": [
        "*"
    ],
    "ExposeHeaders": [
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"
    ],
    "MaxAgeSeconds": 3000
},
{
    "AllowedHeaders": [
        "*"
    ],
    "AllowedMethods": [
        "GET"
    ],
    "AllowedOrigins": [
        "*"
    ],
    "ExposeHeaders": []
}
]
```

This only works on Firefox, **but in Chrome or Edge don't.**

According to the solution of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30317596/cors-configuration-on-aws-s3-not-working) I added `crossOrigin: 'Anonymous'` in the code and CORS:

```
fabric.loadSVGFromURL(url,function(objects, options){

  var obj = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
  obj.scaleToHeight(canvas.height-120).set({ 
    left: (canvas.width / 2) - ((obj.width * obj.scaleX) / 2), 
    top: (canvas.height / 2) - ((obj.height * obj.scaleY) / 2),
    borderColor: '#eaeaea',
    cornerColor:'#eaeaea',
    cornerSize:10,
    cornerStyle:'circle',
    transparentCorners:false,
    lockUniScaling:true,
    fill:"#000000",
    id:"svg_0",
    url_svg: url
 }).setCoords();

canvas.add(obj).renderAll();

},null,{crossOrigin: 'Anonymous'});
```

CORS bucket:

```
[
{
    "AllowedHeaders": [
        "*"
    ],
    "AllowedMethods": [
        "PUT",
        "POST",
        "DELETE"
    ],
    "AllowedOrigins": [
        "*",
        "Anonymous"
    ],
    "ExposeHeaders": [
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"
    ],
    "MaxAgeSeconds": 3000
},
{
    "AllowedHeaders": [
        "*"
    ],
    "AllowedMethods": [
        "GET"
    ],
    "AllowedOrigins": [
        "*",
        "Anonymous"
    ],
    "ExposeHeaders": []
}
]
```

The error is still the same, it works on Firefox, but in Chrome or Edge don't.

I'd like to receive your help.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem and managed to find a seemingly working solution in a blogpost :
https://www.hacksoft.io/blog/handle-images-cors-error-in-chrome

This seems related to your problem (svg not loading and triggering a CORS error, only on Chromium browser).

Basically the way Chromium handles cache makes it break CORS api calls in certain instances.

**The solution** that worked for me was to add "?no-cache" to the api url in the request (the exact text is irrelevant here, just need to pass a param to the api url to force a no-cache use)